# How do you update or override a non-pluggable function located in woocommerce wc-template-functions

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am building a theme in woocommerce and I have a need to make a small change to the html output by the `woocommerce_output_all_notices()` in `wc-template-functions.php`.
The existing function itself is like so:

```
function woocommerce_output_all_notices() {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">';
    wc_print_notices();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

What I'd like to do is simply add an id or data attribute and a `<span>` inside the div, but without editing the code directly (which I clearly don't want to do) I am stumped as it doesn't appear to be a pluggable function and I don't see a way that I can use a hook for this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the action that executes the above function should work.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
```

then add a new action that returns what you need

```
function custom_woocommerce_output_all_notices() {
    // Change your code here.
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">';
    wc_print_notices();
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'custom_woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
```

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you. I was focusng on the function itself rather than the hook that called it. I didn't even consider looking at woocommerce_before_single_product.

Comment: No problem. This is mostly from memory, so I might have the wrong hook name there. Give it a try & let us know how it goes. GL

Comment: This doesn't (always) work with AJAX because WooCommerce specifically adds content inside `woocommerce-notices-wrapper` div.  So if you want to add some HTML inside `woocommerce-notices-wrapper` but before the notice itself (e.g. wrap it in a Boostrap `container`) you're out of luck.